# How to list multiple ".pm" modules in dist.ini (Dist::Zilla)

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

I made a module - [FASTX::Reader](https://metacpan.org/release/FASTX-Reader) - that consisted of a single .pm file, and packaged it with Dist::Zilla.

Now I added two more related modules. I did not change anything in [dist.ini](https://metacpan.org/source/PROCH/FASTX-Reader-0.89/dist.ini) and this does not stop `dzil` to package everything and all the modules are shown in [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/release/FASTX-Reader).

I was wondering, is there a way of explicitly advertising the modules in a package in dist.ini?
What is the recommended method of dealing with multi .pm packages?

PS: I understand the question is vague but my limited  knowledge in modules makes this hard, but I'd like to understand a little bit more. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you said it's working?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla), the `main_module` is derived from the distribution name. So if you have `name  = FASTX-Reader` in your `dist.ini`, the main module will be `lib/FASTX/Reader.pm`. So even if you add more modules to the `lib` folder it will still use `lib/FASTX/Reader.pm` for deriving version and other stuff

Comment: Yes I feel dumb now. It looks working to me but just wanted to be sure that not explicitly mentioning the modules would not impact some aspects of module management I ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there is no need (and possibly no way) of explicitly listing the provided modules in dist.ini.
As [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%C3%A5kon-h%C3%A6gland) noted, there is a main module (the one in `name = Module::Name` in dist.ini) that will be used for deriving the version of the package.